# issue while creating index in elastic search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

When i am trying to create an index for a new table with the command -

```
model_name__elasticsearch__create_index!
```

It is throwing me this error-

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.read_only_allow_delete] did you mean [index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete]?"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.read_only_allow_delete] did you mean [index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete]?"},"status":400}
```

I dont understand what i am doing wrong, i am very new to elasticsearch and any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your requirements do not include very advanced search, I would recommend you to use `searchkick` gem which is built on `elasticsearch-rails` and provide esay to use implementation for mapping and query dsl. https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

Comment: otherwise can you please provide mapping logic too